# What does the number following the argument represent?

Tags: python, arguments, typeerror

I was wondering what the number following the argument stands for (In the error message; the number is 1).

I am updating PsychoPy, and it showed the error message. I have searched for a while, but I did not find any explanation about it.

```
def onCancel(self, event):
    self.app.updater = None
    self.Close()

def onFileBrowse(self, event):
    self.filename = event.GetString()

def onInstall(self, event):
    if self.currentSelection == self.useLatestBtn:
        info = self.doAutoInstall()
    else:
        info = self.installZipFile(self.filename)
    self.statusMessage.SetLabel(info)
    self.Fit()
```

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\PsychoPy3\lib\site- 
packages\psychopy\app\connections\updates.py", line 404, in onInstall
    self.statusMessage.SetLabel(info)
TypeError: Control.SetLabel(): argument 1 has unexpected type 'int'
```

Comment: Error is saying `info` is `int` type. It seems like your `self.statusMessage.SetLabel()` doesn't accept `int`.

Comment: The number simply specifies which function argument it's referring to.  If a function call has three arguments, and it wants to refer the second one, it will say "argument 2".

Comment: Use`@` with his name like  @TomKarzes, to get notifications to the person you have commented. What is your doubt here? your error is with this `self.statusMessage.SetLabel()` method. This is not present in your question.

Comment: Thank you both. In the asking questions part, I would like to know the representation of the number following the argument. I am also bewildered about the error, but I consider the question is specified on PsychoPy and I will ask the questions in the PsychoPy forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @TomKarzes points out in the comments, it's just plain English: `argument 1` is referring to the first argument. `argument 2` would refer to the second argument and so on.